# Problems mosaicing Worldview

Tags: qgis, image-mosaic

I have been trying to mosaic two Worldview images together using the QGIS merge tool. However, the result produces a very noticeable offset.

Having visually checked the original images, they do have a small offset from each other.

Have people encountered this in the past. If so, how did you solve it?

[image: the merged image]

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the issue was?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I used different sources of data instead. I believe it could have been anything from an orthorecitification issue, a projection issue or an image registration problem. Thank you for your help though

Answer (score 1):

Where have the worldview images come from? I'm wondering if one (or both) was clipped and had its extents altered. Looking at your 2 images it appears that the right image is larger than the left, perhaps indicating something like that to be the case?